# Who need to release memory of system call that return char*

Tags: c++, c

if i call to function like `inet_ntoa` that return char*.
Who is responsible to free the allocated memory?

My method look like this:

```
char* inet_aton_(unsigned int atonIp){
    in_addr sin_addr;
    sin_addr.s_addr = atonIp;
    return inet_ntoa(sin_addr);
}
```

Comment: Also note that `inet_ntoa` is deprecated, primarily because of the static buffer issue. You should be using `getnameinfo` with `NI_NUMERICHOST` or at least `inet_ntop`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check the manual for that.

$man inet_ntoa

> ...
>   The inet_ntoa()  function converts the Internet host address in, given
>   in network byte order, to a string  in  IPv4  dotted-decimal  notation.
>   The  string  is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subse‐
>   quent calls will overwrite.

This means in your application you'll have a statically allocated buffer, and you are responsible for what's in there. Each call to inet_ntoa() in your application will override this area. If you need to keep for example two addresses you have to copy this data to another buffer. You are also responsible for using in a correct way in a threaded application, for example if you have two threads calling inet_ntoa at the same time you'll either get wrong results or two seperate calls to inet_ntoa with different parameters will return the same result.

You should also look into source code when you have this kind of questions. For example if you search for "inet_ntoa source". You may encounter some examples; [freebsd](http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/libkern/inet_ntoa.c.html) or [ms](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/winshim/inet_ntoa.c.htm). One example implementation is below (from freebsd).

```
char *
inet_ntoa(struct in_addr ina)
{
    static char buf[4*sizeof "123"];
    unsigned char *ucp = (unsigned char *)&ina;

    sprintf(buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d",
        ucp[0] & 0xff,
        ucp[1] & 0xff,
        ucp[2] & 0xff,
        ucp[3] & 0xff);
    return buf;
}
```

As you can see it has a statically buffer allocated only for this purpose. This makes usage of inet_ntoa very easy since you don't need to manage the buffer but also makes it not thread safe.

Another thing, inet_ntoa is not a system call. It can be called a convenience function provided by inet library.

Comment: Yep , so it , but didnt understand what its mean  - "The  string  is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite" . what is the meaning in subsequent calls? for how long i can be sure that this memory exist? can it be in extreme cases that right after call it the memory overrided by subsequent

Comment: @user1495181: It means inet_ntoa looks like this `char inet_ntoa(...) { static char static_buff[]; ...fill static_buff...; return static_buff; };` It's not thread-safe, so prefer `inet_ntop` instead.

Comment: @auselen the buffer that allocated is only for this call ? it seems to me strange that i need to add lock on this call to prevent 2 thread to call it at the same time.
Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Roddy i read the man of inet_ntop i didnt see any thread-safe there. why did you suggest using it except support fot IPV6?

Comment: @user1495181 - because inet_ntop requires you to pass in the address of the buffer to fill its inherently threadsafe.

Comment: @Roddy sorry i was confused because i saw that it return const char * . Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr):

> The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

This implies that nobody needs to nor should attempt to release the memory.

Answer (score 1):

So, first off; those functions have been deprecated because they don't support IPv6.  Secondly ... consult the documentation.  When a function returns a pointer it should be clearly documented as to who is responsible for deallocating it.

In this case, you are not responsible for deallocating it (nor should you!).

> inet_ntoa() returns the dots-and-numbers string **in a static buffer** that is overwritten with each call to the function.

Comment: So if lots of thread call it in parallel the return char* memory can be override?

Comment: @user1495181: It's not thread safe.  The static buffer is overwritten on each call.